# Using C# dll from C++ project via CLR - is there analogue of LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress functions?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clr

I'm connecting from c++ solution from CLR project to the C# dll. Now I do it using

```
#using <MyDotNet.dll>
```

But for this I need this dll to be present at a compile time, which became a problem. Is there a LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress analogue function for using C# dll from CLR code, so I don't need to have dll at a compile time and the needed method will be invoked from the dll at the runtime?

Comment: @jdweng I don't really understand. You mean to write in my CLR project class with same method name in the same namespace name that the C# method I'm calling? I think it will be some inking error when I will build my C++ solution

Comment: see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682347/loading-library-dynamically

Comment: Why would it cause a linking error.  When you finish the CLR project you simply replace the dummy with the real.

Comment: @jdweng sorry, again don't  understand. Finish what? Problem is that on the compile time I should be able to compile CLR project without C# dll, and use it only in the runtime

Comment: Your c++ project.  All I'm say is to design you c++ project by determing the methods with their inputs and output.  You do not have to rite the code inside the methods just define the methods.  Then you can compile your c# code.  Often for testing people create methods with that return test data so the c# can be debugged without the dlls.